# How to insert field in all documents if it doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, optimization, database, nosql

I am trying to insert a field in every document of a collection if this field doesn't exist before. To do so, I am trying to:

```
db.people.update(
   { city.postcode: "" },
   {
      city.postcode: "W1"
   },
   { multi: true }
)
```

But it's not working unfortunately; any hint please?

**UPDATE**:

Documentation here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing `$set` here:

If you want to update record if `city.postcode": ""` then use following query:

```
db.collection.update( { "city.postcode: "" }, {$set:{ "city.postcode": "W1"}}, { multi: true, upsert: true } )
```

If you want to update record if `city.postcode"` not exists then use following query:

```
db.collection.update( { "city.postcode": {$exist:false} }, {$set:{ "city.postcode": "W1"}}, { multi: true, upsert: true } )
```

Comment: This one is working: db.order.update(
{ $and: [{'city.postcode': { $exists: false }}]} , { $set: {'city.postcode': 'W1' }}, {multi: true})       It's very similar to yours, so I guess yours it's working as well and I'll mark it as the right one. However I break another collection (I mistakenly executed this query over them) Do you know how can I revert it?

Comment: @stackpepe you can not revert it,If it is updated. But you can again update it to remove previously updated field. If updated collection did not contains `city.pincode` earlier then just [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) `city.postcode` field

Comment: Also you do not need `$and` in above query.

Comment: It should be `$exists` (not `$exist`)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
db.people.update(
   { city.postcode: {$exists: false} },
   { city.postcode: "W1"},
   { multi: true, upsert: true }
)
```

Comment: First of all try to do a `db.people.find({ city.postcode: {$exists: false} })` to see if records are selected. If think your query isn't getting any record.

Answer (score 0):

@stackpepe Try this query to update all document

```
db.people.update( {},{ $set: { city.postcode: "W1" },{ multi: true } })
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, MongoDB driver ^4.0

```
   db.people.updateMany({"city.postcode": {$exists:false}}, {$set:{"city.postcode":"W1"}})
```